# Не удаётся обнаружить "Общую папку" в гостевой ОС WinXP

Tags: virtualbox

Здравствуйте! Будьте добры, подскажите пожалуйста, нужно ли предварительно создавать подключение по локальной сети между основной и гостевой ОС в VirtualBox для настройки общей папки? И если да, то как это сделать?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Для работы расшареной папки не важно наличие сетевого соединения между гостевой и хост системы.

1. Скачайте и подключите образ дополнения VBoxGuestAdditions.iso как cdrom. Установите дополнение в гостевой системе;
2. В настройках виртуальной машины укажите папку на хост системе, которую собираетесь подключить и укажите имя шары {share_name};
3. Доступ к папке в гостевой системе:

> (cmd)% \\vboxsvr{share_name}

Для подключения папки {share_name} как диск x:

> (cmd)% net use x: \\vboxsvr{share_name}